# Primary /Foreign Key in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have created an entity class in my MVC 3 application. One of the attribute named RegistryId is primary key as well as foreign key. How can I make a column primary key as well as Foreign key ? I am not using EF ORM designer. I am coding classes by hand.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think by "not using EF ORM designer" you mean new `DbContext` API from EF 4.1. Because if you don't mean `DbContext` API you still have to use EDMX (designer).

You can either use data annotations (`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`): `KeyAttribute` and `ForeignKeyAttribute`:

```
public class Registry
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MyEntity MyEntity { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Registry")]
    public virtual int RegistryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Registry Registry { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can use fluent API (overriding `OnModelCreating` in your derived context):

(Edit: fluent mapping was reversed and incomplete)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                .HasKey(e => e.RegistryId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                .Property(e => e.RegistryId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Registry)
                .WithRequiredDependent(r => r.MyEntity);
}
```

Where `MyEntity` is your entity with FK and `Registry` is principal entity in 1:1 relationship.

Comment: With one-to-many primary key in MyEntity can't be foreign key. There must be either other FK property or no FK property.

Comment: @Ladislav: When I try to use [ForeignKEy("")], It asks for column name. do I need to give Registry inside it or Registry entity's Id ?

Comment: You are the greatest in the world for typing this.  Thank you.

Comment: @Ladislav: You're the man! :D I've read a lot of material on the internet but none of them helped. This is a simple and effective answer. God bless your life! :)

Comment: @Ladislav: Can you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5825799/114029

Comment: I have a question regarding this solution: is there a way to have this same scenario but without having a navigation property <code>Registry</code> on <code>MyEntity</code>, meaning I want a one way navigation only: from principal to dependent only.

Comment: Thanks. Really helped out with a difficult mapping on an existing database.

Comment: why is the Primary key of MyEntity RegistryId?

Comment: @Kryan: Because that was part of question.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: where does it say that `RegistryID`'s value is bound to `Registry`'s?

Comment: This is a very good answer, but, is there any solution that does not imply that I have to change my model to add foreign key properties to objects that hold navigation properties?

Comment: @IsaacLlopis: This answer targets one-to-one relation where foreign key is also primary key (you cannot have entity without primary key). If you model one-to-many relation you don't have to add foreign key properties to your dependent entities - that is a difference between [independent and foreign key association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275) in EF but it has its consequences.

Comment: @Ladislav: I've been looking for a solution to this problem, and found it right here! Thank you for your explanation!