# Delete many records per ID - MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, cascade

The setup for the database I have is, `Company` can have many `Engineer`, and can be in many `Territory`. If I am supposed to remove a company form the list, I need to make a clean exit, so instead of deleting just the Company form the company table. I have to make sure all records are deleted everywhere. So no child/related records become orphan data.

If I am to remove just one record from all the tables, I would simply delete it using `FirstOrDefault`, then I could use

```
public void RemoveCompany(long companyId)
{
    using (var db = new BoilerServicingDbContext())
    {
        var ec = db.Engineers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyId == companyId);
        db.Engineers.Remove(ec);
        var tc = db.CompanyTerritories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyId == companyId);
        db.CompanyTerritories.Remove(tc);
        var p = db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id ==  companyId);
        db.Companies.Remove(p);
        db.SaveChanges();       
    }
}
```

However, there are more than one Engineer per company and more than one Territory per company. Is there a simple method, as in general database sense.

```
DELETE * FROM Engineers WHERE companyId = 1;
```

At this moment I do not have Cascading delete setup, so other than that. Any other options.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Comment: Thank you @CodeCaster, I will look at the SQL version after getting the EF working. Much appreciated !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not to use `.Where()` method to find all corresponding items in DB? Like this:

```
foreach(var ec in db.Engineers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId))
{
    db.Engineers.Remove(ec);
}
// same logic here for other tables
```

Also consider the @workabyte answer as there is a way to implement `cascade delete` in your database.

Comment: I imagined there were to be a simpler method to delete in one line. This has done it for me though. Thank you ever so much !

Comment: Also consider the @workabyte answer as there is a way to implement `cascade delete` in your database.

Comment: Absolutely. Cascade on Delete was the first option, but I was not sure if there were other possibilities. :)

Comment: I brought this up in the C# chatroom and the general consensus is that using an ORM to do batch operations is probably a bad idea and you should use stored commands instead.

Comment: Personally I prefer no use ORM at all :)

Answer (score 2):

One option could be cascade on delete, you have to tell EF to do this for you as it will not by default, something like this should do it. Also linked to a couple other SO answers that have similar appeal for some extra reading.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
        .HasMany(b => b.Engineer)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9241880/546411

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14493591/546411

Comment: Thank you, I might make it Cascade on Delete. At this point of time, I am trying to delete through code. :)

Comment: @PaulFrancis, you would delete the parent record via code that would cause the rest to delete so that you dont have to loop through a bunch of records. Code well, glad you found an answer

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I am just getting my teeth into C#, so learning all possibilities. Since Cascade on delete is something that would be very easy to achieve, I was thinking all other twisted ways. ;) +1 for providing me with alternate answer ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use plain SQL if you don't mind using the table name (most efficient):

```
public void RemoveCompany(long companyId)
{
    using (var db = new BoilerServicingDbContext())
    {
        var engineerIds = db.Engineers
                            .Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId)
                            .Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

        var sql  = "DELETE FROM Engineers WHERE Id IN ({0})";
        sql = string.Format(sql, string.Join(", ", engineerIds);
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
        db.SaveChanges();       
    }
}
```

Comment: just curious, not attacking. can you elaborate on the efficiency of this method?

Comment: It's not more efficient than a cascading delete, but more efficient than generating one SQL statement per delete. (will also not map the engineer object hierarchy (if any))

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended).
Its a library that extends EF and (amongst other things) provide batch update/delete methods.

In your case:

```
int companyid = 1;

context.Engineers.Delete(x=>x.CompanyId == companyid)
context.CompanyTerritories.Delete(x=>x.CompanyId == companyid)
context.Companies.Delete(x=>x.CompanyId == companyid)
```

Answer (score 0):

In EF6 it's much easier Using **RemoveRange** and without foreach:

```
db.Engineers.RemoveRange(db.Engineers.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId));
db.SaveChanges();
```