# Why EF generate invalid column when i have same column name as Foreign key in child table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I got these 2 models, i use "include" to get all related entities and my LINQ is look like this, when i execute it will complain -- `Invalid column Cust_ProfileTbl_bintAccountNo`

**LINQ**

```
DB context = new DB();
List<Cust_ProfileTbl> profile = context.profile.ToList();
var r = from ord in context.profile.Include("balance") 
        select ord;
```

**Models**

```
public class Cust_ProfileTbl   
{
    [Key]
    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; } 
    public virtual  BP_BalanceTbl balance { get; set; } 
} 
public class BP_BalanceTbl
{
    [Key] 
    public long bintAccountNo { get; set; } 
}
```

**Generated SQL**

```
SELECT  
    [Project1].[bintAccountNo] AS [bintAccountNo], 
    [Project1].[Cust_ProfileTbl_bintAccountNo] AS [Cust_ProfileTbl_bintAccountNo]-- Invalid column
    FROM ( 
        SELECT 
            [Extent1].[bintAccountNo] AS [bintAccountNo], 
            [Extent2].[Cust_ProfileTbl_bintAccountNo] AS [Cust_ProfileTbl_bintAccountNo], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[intPartner] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Cust_ProfileTbl] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[BP_BalanceTbl] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[bintAccountNo] = [Extent2].[Cust_ProfileTbl_bintAccountNo]

    )  AS [Project1] 
ORDER BY [Project1].[bintAccountNo] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

Things i tried to get rid this bug

1. Add 1 Identity PK column into BP_BalanceTbl, (Which i don't feel like to do)
2. Change to use Join method. ( but i want to know why this happened not just run away from error, and how to avoid this?)

Comment: in BP_BalanceTbl, is bintAccountNo not a FK?

Comment: Yes,  bintAccountNo is foreign key. We separate the table (Cust_Profiletbl) into 2 tables because of too many column. So the  bintAccountNo  in BP_BalanceTbl we create it as PK also.

Comment: so it's both PK and FK?  is that not the cause of the problem?

Comment: Yes.What's wrong if it is 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: Sorry, nothing wrong - I mean I just wondered if EF having an problem creating the FK because of it.

Comment: Yes it is obviously is cause by PK and FK column. But is there a way to solve it or i got no choice to remove the PK by adding another identity PK Column.

Comment: There will be a solution, a quick search found this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388077/primary-foreign-key-in-entity-framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388077/primary-foreign-key-in-entity-framework)

Comment: @markpsmith thanks, your link point me to solution. Obviously by finding solution base on error message is not ideal. ;). +1. I'll mark it as answer if you not mind put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the request of the OP, I'm posting my comment as an answer:

So the problem is based on the fact that a model property is assigned both Primary and Foreign Keys. To tell EF to create this you need to use DataAnnotations on the property:

```
[Key, ForeignKey("Cust_ProfileTbl")]
public long bintAccountNo { get; set; }
```

and also you'll probably need to reference the related entity as a virtual property:

```
public virtual Cust_ProfileTbl{get; set;}
```

Comment: hi, should be look like this on 2nd line public virtual Cust_ProfileTbl profile { get; set; }  and also this is needed for foreignkey. :) thanks.